Is Moral Attraction the Key to Avoiding Berkeleyean Solipsism?
Bishop Berkeley’s philosophy is often characterized as idealist, but this is a hasty generalization and false advertising. It is deeply empirical, grounded in observations about human perception and cognition. His ideas have had a significant influence on later philosophers and the Scottish Enlightenment. There is anecdotal evidence to suggest that Berkeley came to the attention of the Scottish Rankenian Club as early as the 1720s. In his seldom consulted Essay on Moral Attraction, as early as 1713, Berkeley was already talking of sensus commmunis and the grounding of human morality in compassion and sympathy. He writes:

Hence that sympathy in our nature whereby we feel the pains and joys of our fellow creatures[...] In a word, hence arises that diffusive sense of Humanity so unaccountable to the selfish man who is untouched with it, and is, indeed, a sort of monster or anomalous production.

Not only are we in bodily communication with "fellow creatures," but this implies that there are no isolated, solitary-confined minds. My mind and your mind depend upon an ensemble of minds. His emphasis on the role of perception and the mind in constituting reality suggests a subjective basis for sympathy and compassion. That is, these feelings are based on our perceptions and mental associations, which are shaped by our experiences and interactions with others. If we read Berkeley's ethics as a precursor for many of the moral values of the Scottish enlightenment, to what extent can we still brand his philosophy idealist? To what extent does Berkeley's ethics take precedence over his epistemological claims, or are the separate and distinct spheres of inquiry?

We do not need Berkeley's ethics to take precedence over his epistemological claims because his  epistemological, and ontological, claims are already plainly non-solipsistic. He posits multiple minds with God coordinating them, there is no solipsistic outlook of weaving the world out of one's own mind. Of course, his world is mind-based rather than matter-based and that makes him an idealist, but which substance happens to be ontologically primary, mind or matter,  has nothing to do with theses of solipsism. Berkeley's 'solipsism' is just an uninformed misunderstanding of his philosophy.
